# Python NSFW detection module nudenet not longer working?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, onnx

I have been using the python module *nudenet* for my final degree project. I'm using google colab to run it.

It worked correctly and without any problem during this last months until yesterday, when I tried to import it, this error happenend:

```
!pip install --upgrade nudenet
from nudenet import NudeClassifier

ImportError: cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I tried to solve this error by downgrading *opencv-python-headless* to a previous version

```
!pip uninstall opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 
!pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.1.48
```

But then, when I load the classifier this error appears:

```
classifier = NudeClassifier()


Downloading the checkpoint to /root/.NudeNet/classifier_model.onnx
MB| |#                                                | 0 Elapsed Time: 0:00:00
Content-length not found, file size cannot be estimated.
Succefully Downloaded to: /root/.NudeNet/classifier_model.onnx

InvalidProtobuf: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 7 : INVALID_PROTOBUF : Load model from /root/.NudeNet/classifier_model.onnx failed:Protobuf parsing failed.
```

I have also tried to downgrade the version of the module nudenet, and still nothing works.

Thank you in advance.

[This is the link for the module in github](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet)

Comment: I'm having the same issue even after downgrading opencv, just as you did. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace the rile classifier_model.onnx with [nudenet classifier](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_model.onnx)
and file classifier_lite.onnx with [nudenet lite classifier](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_lite.onnx)

Comment: Hello, I'm running NudeNet on a Google Colab notebook. How would I go about replacing the .onnx files so I too can get around this issue. Thank you for your time

Comment: I had the same problem and to solve it I cloned the project locally and changed the download link in the code to the locally downloaded file.

Comment: Hello Chandan, how did you find this ? I'm curious to know what was broken and how you fixed it. Thanks a lot